# postgres gem failing to install mac osx sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems, ruby-2.3

This one i cant figure out im running osx sierra but was fine for a while and then all of a sudden when i tried to do a bundle update

ive tried everything i have google and completly reinstalled homebrew and postgres but nothing, any help is very appreciated

i think something that may be wrong is setting the location of postgres

```
   Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.5.4/bin/pg_config
    sh: /usr/pgsql-9.5.4/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
    sh: /usr/pgsql-9.5.4/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
```

i changed something here but dont know what i did and no idea how to get it back

```
    Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory:
    /Users/raycove/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/ext
    /Users/raycove/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r
    ./siteconf20160930-43553-1i5ubpk.rb extconf.rb
    --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.5.4/bin/pg_config
    Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.5.4/bin/pg_config
    sh: /usr/pgsql-9.5.4/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
    sh: /usr/pgsql-9.5.4/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
    checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
    checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
    checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
    checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
    checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
    checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
    checking for PQprepare()... yes
    checking for PQexecParams()... yes
    checking for PQescapeString()... yes
    checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
    checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
    checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
    checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
    checking for lo_create()... yes
    checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
    checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
    checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
    checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
    checking for PQping()... yes
    checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
    checking for PQconninfo()... yes
    checking for PQsslAttribute()... yes
    checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
    checking for rb_enc_alias()... yes
    checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
    checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
    checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
    checking for rb_w32_wrap_io_handle()... no
    checking for rb_str_modify_expand()... yes
    checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
    checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... yes
    checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... yes
    checking for PG_DIAG_TABLE_NAME in libpq-fe.h... yes
    checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for ruby/st.h... yes
    checking for C99 variable length arrays... yes
    creating extconf.h
    creating Makefile

    To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
    be found here:

    /Users/raycove/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/pg-0.19.0/mkmf.log

    current directory:
    /Users/raycove/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/ext
    make "DESTDIR=" clean

    current directory:
    /Users/raycove/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/ext
    make "DESTDIR="
    compiling gvl_wrappers.c
    compiling pg.c
    compiling pg_binary_decoder.c
    compiling pg_binary_encoder.c
    compiling pg_coder.c
    compiling pg_connection.c
    compiling pg_copy_coder.c
    compiling pg_errors.c
    compiling pg_result.c
    compiling pg_text_decoder.c
    compiling pg_text_encoder.c
    compiling pg_type_map.c
    compiling pg_type_map_all_strings.c
    compiling pg_type_map_by_class.c
    compiling pg_type_map_by_column.c
    compiling pg_type_map_by_mri_type.c
    compiling pg_type_map_by_oid.c
    compiling pg_type_map_in_ruby.c
    compiling util.c
    linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle
    ld: file not found: dynamic_lookup
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1

    make failed, exit code 2

    Gem files will remain installed in
    /Users/raycove/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0 for
    inspection.
    Results logged to
    /Users/raycove/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/pg-0.19.0/gem_make.out

    An error occurred while installing pg (0.19.0), and Bundler cannot
    continue.
    Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.19.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12273968/981616

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010004/so-i-installed-postgresql-and-localhost-port-conflicting-with-ruby-app/39010110#39010110